# Remove controller name from URLs in Yii2

Tags: php, seo, yii2

How can I remove the controller name from URLs in Yii2?

I'm aware of simple aliases, but I'm not sure how to apply aliases to a little bit more complex rule, like the following one:

```
'rules' => [
    'public/<seo_url:.*?>/<category_id:\d+>/<product_id:\d+>' => 'public/product'
]
```

This will create a rule so URLs like `/product/this-is-a-slug/94/12` will call the `actionProduct` in my `Public` controller.

How can I make an alias that would call that same action if I try to access a product using this URL: `/this-is-a-slug/94/12` ?

Answer (score 1):

Set new rulw on top of all rules. Like that:

```
'rules' => [
    '<seo_url:.*?>/<category_id:\d+>/<product_id:\d+>' => 'public/product',
]
```

This is work for me.

Comment: Yeah, that will work, but that way I'll have to create 2 rules for each URL. Not that I pretend having 10000 different rules, but still, it doesn't look like the cleanest solution.

Comment: Please, take me examples.