# Yii2: Remove controller from URL

Tags: model-view-controller, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, friendly-url, pretty-urls

I am using the advanced template.
I created all my actions on the SiteController, so all my urls are domain.com/site/something, and I need to remove the word "site" from the url so it will be domain.com/something.

I tried the following rules based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577022/remove-controller-name-from-urls-in-yii2)

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => array(
                '/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'site/<action>',
                '/<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>',
                '/noticia/<slug>' => 'site/noticia',
        ),
    ],
```

also tried this based on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38272745/yii2-how-to-remove-site-index-and-page-parameter-from-url):

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'baseUrl' => 'http://localhost/websites/transcita/app/frontend/web',
        'rules' => array(
                [
                    'pattern' => '<action:\w+>',
                    'route' => 'site/<action>'
                 ],
                [
                    'pattern' => '<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>',
                    'route' => 'site/<action>'
                 ],
                '/noticia/<slug>' => 'site/noticia',
        ),
    ],
```

but neither is not working. I get a 404 when I type domain.com/something.
I also tried without the first / and it didn't work either.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enableStrictParsing' => false,
    'rules' => [

        // ...

        // last rule
        '<action:(.*)>' => 'site/<action>',
    ],
],
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This worked perfectly! Would you happen to have a link where I can read up on the difference between \w+ and (.*), because that change did the trick.

Comment: Here you can find excellent explaination of reg expr: https://regex101.com/ . \w+ matches any letter, number or underscore, instead .* maches zero or more charaters. Maybe your action are composed more than one word.

Answer (score 9):

Another way:

```
'rules' => [
    '<alias:\w+>' => 'site/<alias>',
],
```

Comment: this way is better, because first answer gives 404 error for all other controllers (not SiteController)